# If $F_0\cap G_0=\emptyset$ then $x$ is a local minimum of function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, maxima-minima

Consider the theorem:

[image: Theorem statement]

> Consider the following linear optimization problem $$\max 2x_1+3x_2$$ $$\text{s.t.} x_1+x_2\le8\\ -x_1+2x_2\le4\\ x_1,x_2\ge0$$
>
> a) For each extreme point verify if necessary condition of theorem is satisfied.
>
> b)Find the optimal solution and justify the optimality of the solution.

First we switch the problem to $\min$. Thus we have $$\min -2x_1-3x_2$$ $$s.t. x_1+x_2\le8\\ -x_1+2x_2\le4\\ x_1,x_2\ge0$$

Drawing the feasible region we found that there are only 3 extreme points: $A=(0,2),B=(4,4),C=(0,8)$.

Notice that $A$ is the only point that satisfies the constraint conditions.

Now we try to see that $F_0\cap G_0=\emptyset$. We first calculate the gradients

$\nabla f(A)=(-2,-3)^t,\nabla g_1(A)=(1,1)^t,\nabla g_2(A)=(-1,2)^t$.

And $\nabla f(A)^td=-2d_1-3d_2$

$\nabla g_1(A)^td=d_1+d_2$

$\nabla g_2(A)^td=-d_1+d_2$

We ask the 3 of them to be less than zero.

**My question** is how can I check that $F_0\cap G_0=\emptyset$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More systematic way to do that is to use Gordan's theorem (e.g. you can find it in *Bazaraa et al*, Theorem 2.4.9). You need to check that the system
$$
Ad=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\-1 & 1\\-2 & -3\end{bmatrix}d<0
$$
is inconsistent. It is equivalent to existence of a non-zero solution to
$$
A^Tp=0,\quad p\ge 0.
$$
It is easier in general to deal with equalities because one may use the standard elimination technique:
$$
A^T=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & -2\\ 1 & 1 & -3
\end{bmatrix}\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & -2\\ 0 & 2 & -1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Thus all the solutions to $A^Tp=0$ are
$$
\begin{cases}
p_1&=p_2+2p_3,\\
2p_2&=p_3.
\end{cases}
$$
It is easy to find a positive solution e.g. if we take $p_3=2$, we get $p=(5,1,2)$, hence, the original system of inequalities is inconsistent and $F_0\cap G_0=\emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you for your help $A.\Gamma.$ I didn't know one could use that theorem to solve this optimization problems :). I think there's just a little typo in you answer, it should be $2p_3$ instead of $p_3$?

Comment: @user441848 Yes, thank you! It is a good sign that you can find errors, it means that you actually follow and understand.

Comment: haha of course I hardly ever accept an answer that I don't completely understand

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you could take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2824474/kkt-conditions-holds-true-under-cottless-constraint-qualifications please :)?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $d_1+d_2<0$ and $-d_1+d_2<0$ implies that $d_2<-|d_1|$, or $-d_2>|d_1|$. Hence $-2d_1-3d_2>-2d_1+3|d_1|\geqslant0$ for all $d_1\in\mathbb{R}$.

You can also draw a picture (good for these 2d geometric problems):

[image: Intersection of sets]

Comment: This is a really good way to check if the intersection of the sets is empty, but solving the problem using this technique in an exam could be not a good idea because of the scale draws are ususally not exact as software is. And hence can confuse us.

Comment: The picture was intended for intuition—I also included the _ad hoc_ algebraic proof. For a general answer, see what A.G. did.

Comment: oh ok thank you, what's _ad hoc_ ?

Comment: It’s a latin phrase, that means “for this.” So my approach is _ad hoc_ because it only really applies _for this_ particular problem. The other answer gives a more general approach.

Comment: ah I see :P ${}$