# KKT conditions holds true under Cottles's constraint qualifications?

Tags: optimization, proof-explanation, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

**Exercise**

[image]

> Solution:
>
> [image]

Could someone please explain why the reached contradiction solves the exercise?

I can understand the solution but I don't know how does that implies that $\overline x$ is a KKT point.

---

Here is how I interprete the solution.

We suppose $u_0=0,$ hence if $\sum_{i\in I} u_i\nabla g_i(\overline x)=0$ has solution then it must be nonzero. As we found a contradiction, then do we must have that the system  $\sum_{i\in I} u_i\nabla g_i(\overline x)=0$ has no solution?

or what could we say about it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bar x$ is FJ point. It means, in particular, that not all among $u_0,u_i$, $i\in I$, are zeros.

Assume $u_0=0$ then not all $u_i$, $i\in I$, are zeros. It leads to contradiction with Cottle's constraint qualification.

> The contradiction ensures that $u_0\ne 0$.

Since $u_0\ne 0$ we can divide the first FJ equation by $u_0$ to get
$$
\nabla f(\bar x)+\sum_{i\in I}\Big(\frac{u_i}{u_0}\Big)\nabla g_i(\bar x)=0.
$$
This is exactly the first KKT condition with the new coefficients $\tilde u_i=\frac{u_i}{u_0}$.

P.S. The wording "hence if $\sum_{i\in I} u_i\nabla g_i(\overline x)=0$ has solution then it must be nonzero" is not correct. The system always has a trivial solution $u_i=0$, and the conclusion "then it is nonzero" is not true for the trivial solution. The correct conclusion is that there exists at least one more solution except for the trivial one.

Comment: got it, so the solution (in the pic) that is in the question it's not complete, it was not complete that's why I didn't understand

Comment: I know this has nothing to do with the question, anyway hope you answer me (yes or no it's ok). Is it possible to have extreme points in a set and that they are not feasibles?

Comment: @user441848 I do not really understand the question. Feasible points are exactly points in the set. Could you provide more details?

Comment: This is the exercise: $\max 2x+3y\\ s.t. x+y\le 8\\ -x+2y\le 4\\ x,y\ge0$. For each extreme point, verify of KKT conditions holds and then find the optimal solution. I found 4 extreme points. $A=(0,0)^t,B=(8,0)^t,C=(4,4)^t,D=(0,2)^t.$ Then I calculated the gradients. $\nabla f(x)=(2,3)^t,\nabla g_1(x)=(1,1)^t,\nabla g_2(x)=(-1,2)^t$. Thus if we evaluate in each gradient the  extreme points, the gradients won't change. Then I tried to solve the KKT system and I got $u_1=\frac{-7}{3}$ and $u_2=\frac{-1}{3}$ thus none extreme point would be a KKT point.

Comment: oh I think my question was not well formulated before , I think it should have been: Is it possible to have extreme points in a set and that they are not optimal?

Comment: I know I've bothered a lot  (but this is the last time), could you please take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827744/cone-of-tangents-is-a-subset-of-d-in-mathbb-rn-mid-nabla-g-i-overline-xtd  ?

Comment: @user441848 KKT works for minimization. Your problem here is **maximization**. To apply KKT you have to convert it first to $\max(2x+3y)=-\min(-2x-3y)$. Thus $f(x,y)=-2x-3y$. You also have **four** constraints ($x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$ produce $g_3=-x$ and $g_4=-y$). The extreme point where KKT condition for *active* constraints hold is $(4,4)$.

Comment: oh you're right. I did convert the problem from maximization to minimization but for some reason I worked with maximization problem.. and I completely forget about the other constraints $g_3=-x$ and $g_4=-y$ :( I'll correct it