# Cone of tangents is a subset of $\{d\in\mathbb R^n\mid\nabla g_i(\overline x)^td\le 0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, alternative-proof

[image]

**Attempt**

First off, the cone of tangents of a set $S$ at a point $\overline{x}$ is the set of directions $d$ such that there exists a sequence of scalars $\{\lambda_k\}$ and vectors $\{x_k\}$ for $k=1,2,\dots,$ such that $\lambda_k>0$ for all $k$, $x_k\in{S}$ for all $k$, $x_k\to\overline{x}$ and $d=\lim_{k\to\infty}\lambda_k(x_k-\overline{x})$.

Now suppose $d\in T$ and $d\not\in G'$. As $d\not\in G',$ there exists $d$ such that $\nabla g_i(\overline x)^td>0$ which is equivalent to $-\nabla g_i(\overline x)^td\le0$. From here we deduce that $-\nabla g_i(\overline x)d=0,d\ge0$ has no solution by Gordan's Theorem.

Should I substitute the $d$ by the limit?

From here how can I reach the contradiction?

Could someone guide me please? Did I take a good way to prove it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: We are in $\mathbb R^n,X\subset\mathbb R^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier here to do a direct proof without contradiction: let $d\in T$, we are to prove that $d\in G'$.

Start with Taylor's expansion at $\bar x$ for a $g_i(x)$, $i\in I$:
$$
g_i(x_k)=g_i(\bar x)+\nabla g_i(\bar x)^T(x_k-\bar x)+o(|x_k-\bar x|).
$$
We have

- $g_i(x_k)\le 0$ as $x_k$ is feasible,
- $g_i(\bar x)=0$ as $g_i$ is active at $\bar x$.

It becomes
$$
\nabla g_i(\bar x)^T(x_k-\bar x)+o(|x_k-\bar x|)\le 0.
$$
Multiply by $\lambda _k$ and let $k\to+\infty$. Since $\lambda_k(x_k-\bar x)\to d\in T$, the only think left for you to do here is to motivate that 
$$
\lambda_k\cdot o(|x_k-\bar x|)\to 0,\quad k\to+\infty
$$
and conclude that $d\in G'$.

Comment: wow I wonder how your idea came up

Comment: The error function always goes to zero when $k\to\infty$, am I right? So we have $\lambda_k\cdot o(|x_k-\bar x|)\to 0,\quad k\to+\infty$

Comment: @user441848 Motivation: $o(|x_k-\bar x|)=|x_k-\bar x|\cdot\rho_k$ where $\rho_k\to 0$. Then $\lambda_k|x_k-\bar x|\cdot \rho_k\to|d|\cdot 0=0$.

Comment: Why did you wrote _Motivation:_ :) ? Isn't that the missing part to complete the proof?

Comment: @user441848 It explains why $\lambda_k\cdot o(|x_k-\bar x|)\to 0$. It is not clear from the beginning, because $o(|x_k-\bar x|)$ is small, but $\lambda_k$ is large, so the limit is of the kind $\infty\cdot 0$, which is indeterminate. Motivation is a formal proof why $o(|x_k-\bar x|)$ vanishes faster than $\lambda_k$ explodes to infinity.